# Getting the value of a key in a dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I try to get the value of a key in a `dict` by :

```
print User['LocationName']
```

This is giving me a `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str` error.

This is the dict

```
{u'LocationName': u'home', u'First Name': u'Bob',...... }
```

I'm not sure what this error means

Comment: `{u'LocationName': u'home', u'First Name': u'Bob'}['LocationName']` works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`User` is not a dict. `User` is a string. Figure out why it's a string, and change that.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you are trying to access a "part" of your string as if it was a list. But you are not using a integer as parameter to access a list, you are using a string.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use:

> eval(User)

then you can:

> print User['LocationName']

This usually happens when you save a JSON into a file, using python. It's like Python saved your dict as a dict Object, but when you read from the file, the object is read by string. So, when you call eval(), you get a dict again.